# Select different fields as one field (no CONCAT)

Tags: mysql, sql, field

I have a table with 2 fields, `val1` and `val2`, that contain same type. `val1` is mandatory and `val2` is optional -- but if present, should count as much as `val1`.

```
CREATE TABLE VALS (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
val1 INT NOT NULL,
val2 INT DEFAULT NULL,
timesign TIMESTAMP);
```

For that, I want to retrieve all values, whether coming from `val1` or `val2` field, into one field `res`, so that this

```
INSERT INTO VALS (val1, val2) VALUES
(1, null),
(2, null),
(3, 4),
(5, null),
(6, 7),
(8, null);
```

can be retrieved to one field only:

```
+------+
| res  |
+------+
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
| 6    |
| 7    |
| 8    |
+------+
```

**How to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT val1 as res 
FROM VALS

UNION

SELECT val2 as res  
FROM VALS
WHERE val2 is notNULL;
```

You don't need "distict", Union is itself give set.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I surprised how quickly you make demo. What the Magic? --Thanks!

Comment: Will not work when first column is `null` and the second one is not `null`. If you need that you may see my solution (pretty similar but using having on aliased column)

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I already told you the magic is in the text to ddl option :)

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky yes, because in table state he don't have null so I removed. Additionally notice in create table "val1 INT NOT NULL,"

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky According to OP's sample dateset col2 can be null not the col1, see table definition in the question

Comment: You both are right, and as I said, if someone needs that, more of an addition to the answer rather negation :)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I tried that I couldn't I will give try again thanks to remind me :)

Answer (score 3):

One query with union

```
SELECT a AS f FROM t
UNION 
SELECT b AS f FROM t HAVING f IS NOT NULL ORDER BY f
```

Works when both columns can be `NULL`

Comment: according to table definiton first column is specified NOT null

Comment: yes, you suggestion is helpful otherwise I use `is notNULL;` both place.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan same answer, it doesn't mean it won't work :)

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky yes I mean I like your answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan oh, I see, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
select  resultcol from ( select distict val1 as resultcol from vals union select distinct val2 as resultcol from vals)alias order by resultcol
```

Union remove all duplicate values